# Why has my Samsung Galaxy S2 become a data hog?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, data-monitoring

My father has a Samsung Galaxy S2 with the stock GB and un-rooted. The phone has been working flawlessly, but lately (since about 2-3 days) it began to use a crazy amount of data.

He normally uses about 300 MB per month, but now the phone is using about 20-30 MB per hour **during phone standby!**.

Also he notices is that the battery is lasting about half of the previous time, which is evident in case of a long running process.

He didn't install/update anything lately and all the settings are set for minimal data use. (Like no Sync..etc). He also has all the known data-hog apps kept disabled.

He has installed an app call “[my data manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobidia.android.mdm&hl=en)” and the app says that all the data is being used by OS services but there is no detailed information.

Just for clarification, he doesn’t have too much applications installed. Just: Whatsapp,  Viber, Facebook and Twitter. But as I said before, he has all the auto sync off, and all these apps where installed months ago.

My question is: Is there a program that can help us to find out what is going on? Something like a “on the fly” (real-time) data analysis?

Any other ideas on what could be happening here?

Thanks!
Edgar

Comment: It's possible that the phone is trying to download an over-the-air update to recently released Android 4.0 (ICS).  Check in `Settings -> About phone -> System updates` to see if there's an update available, and download it over Wi-Fi instead.

Comment: Thanks! but that's not the case... :(

Comment: Maybe it's a forced update due to the recent court order in the case against apple?

Comment: Check Facebook, Google + Photos settings to see whether photo upload / sync is enabled. The phone might be trying to get images from Picasa.

Comment: Also check Market settings to see if apps are updating themselves automatically.

Comment: Sparx, all the syncs are off. I will check about the updating in the market, and thanks for the grammar correction! English is my second language!

Answer (score 2):

After reading the comments, there's not much else to suggest for you to check on your phone.

So, here's two free APPs to help you out:

## [My Data Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobidia.android.mdm&hl=en)

**Main features:**
  • Simple to setup and simple to use.
  • Know what apps are using data with automatic monitoring of your app data usage.
  • Set usage alarms to avoid overage charges and “bill shock”.
  • Track historical app time and app usage using easy to understand visualizations.
  • Ensure you are using your ideal data plan and maximize how you use your data.
  • Save money by using your plans more effectively.

[image: My Data Manager print screen]

---

## [3G Watchdog](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.rgruet.android.g3watchdog&feature=related_apps#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEwOSwibmV0LnJncnVldC5hbmRyb2lkLmczd2F0Y2hkb2ciXQ..)

**Main features:**
  • monitors your Mobile Internet (4G/3G/Edge/GPRS) data usage.
  • shows a status icon (green/orange/red) in the notification bar.
  • has a detailed report page.

[image: 3G Watchdog print screen]

Comment: My Data Manager is a free app. There is an outrageously priced paid version that isn't necessary.

Comment: @Zooks64 Tks for the heads-up, I was initially looking at the **My Data Manager Update** version that in fact one needs to pay.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I just realize that in my original post I write My Data Monitor, but I mean my data manager.

I will try 3g watchdog now.

Answer (score 0):

Your father has exactly the same problem as me. It is caused by the email exchange services. I will suggest to download a data monitor app called [HiNet](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chttl.android.traffic) (The app is chinese). Using this app I found out that the email exchange service was consuming a lot of data. Now I wonder  why this email exchange service suddenly went 'crazy' (There were no issues for 5 months).

Comment: Please don't ask questions in answers. You can always ask a new question.